# AWS AppSync Subscriptions Without Websockets

Tags: reactjs, websocket, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

While testing our new webapp that uses AWS's AppSync for the GraphQL backend, we discovered that some of our customers have corporate networks that block websockets. Is there any way to use AppSync subscriptions (we also use AWS Amplify) without websockets?

It would be great to use subscriptions instead of building a polling fallback, but that looks like the only option.

Comment: what transport layer you think it would work for your use case?

Comment: I imagine anything else would work, I was surprised that websockets were not working on the network, but after researching this is not unheard of.

Answer (score 3):

Currently AppSync does it only through web-sockets. 
This is interesting can you please open an issue to the AppSync Community repository here: [awsAppSync.dev](https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/)

I have also passed the request to the team.

Comment: Just for reference, this is the created github issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/17